# Mutiny - How to group items to send request by blocks

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x, quarkus, mutiny

I'm using Mutiny extension (for Quarkus) and I don't know how to manage this problem.

I want to send many request in an async way so I've read about Mutiny extension. But the server closes the connection because it receives thousand of them.

So I need:

- Send the request by blocks
- After all request are sent, do things.

I've been using Uni object to combine all the responses as this:

```
Uni<Map<Integer, String>> uniAll = Uni.combine()
   .all()
   .unis(list)
   .combinedWith(...);
```

And then:

```
uniAll.subscribe()
      .with(...);
```

This code, send all the request in paralell so the server closes the connection.

I'm using group of Multi objects, but I don't know how to use it (in Mutiny docs I can't found any example).

This is the way I'm doing now:

```
          //Launch 1000 request
          for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            multi = client.getAbs("https://api.*********.io/jokes/random")
                      .as(BodyCodec.jsonObject())
                      .send()
                      .onItem().transformToMulti(
                              array -> Multi.createFrom()
                                       .item(array.body().getString("value")))
                                       .group()
                                       .intoLists()
                                       .of(100)
                                       .subscribe()
                                       .with(a->{
                                         System.out.println("Value: "+a);
                                        });
          }
```

I think that the subscription doesn't execute until there are "100" groups of items, but I guess this is not the way because it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to launch 1000 of async requests in blocks of 100?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED 2021-04-19**

I've tried with this approach:

```
    List<Uni<String>> listOfUnis = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        listOfUnis.add(client
                       .getAbs("https://api.*******.io/jokes/random")
                       .as(BodyCodec.jsonObject())
                       .send()
                       .onItem()
                       .transform(item -> item
                                        .body()
                                        .getString("value")));
      }


    Multi<Uni<String>> multiFormUnis = Multi.createFrom()
                                            .iterable(listOfUnis);

    List<String> listOfResponses = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> listOfValues = multiFormUnis.group()
                 .intoLists()
                 .of(100)
                 .onItem()
                 .transformToMultiAndConcatenate(listOfOneHundred -> 
                 {
                     System.out.println("Size: "+listOfOneHundred.size());
                     
                     for (int index=0;index<listOfOneHundred.size();index++) {
                         listOfResponses.add(listOfOneHundred.get(index)
                                                             .await()
                                                             .indefinitely());                          
                     }                       
                
                return Multi.createFrom()
                            .iterable(listOfResponses);
                 })
                 .collectItems()
                 .asList()
                 .await()
                 .indefinitely();

    for (String value : listOfValues) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

When I put this line:

```
 listOfResponses.add(listOfOneHundred.get(index)
                                     .await()
                                     .indefinitely());
```

The responses are printed one after each other, and when the first 100s group of items ends, it prints the next group. The problem? There are sequential requests and it takes **so much time**

I think I am close to the solution, but I need to know, how to send the parallel request only in group of 100s, because if I put:

```
subscribe().with()
```

All the request are sent in parallel (and not in group of 100s)

Comment: As you use the Vert.x WebClient, you can configure the max concurrency using `setMaxPoolSize()`

Comment: To do what you want you need the stream of the 1000 requests and group them into lists of 100. Then, for each group, emit and process the response. Right now, it just creates 1000 multi and all of them emit a single request, get the result and, from what I can see group the responses into group of 100. So definitely not what you described.

Comment: So, can I add the 1000 request to a List of Multi object, then create a Multi form and set the items with that list, then group into other list of 100, and then subscribe that group? Because I don't know how to list of the 1000 requests into lists of 100. Thx

Comment: Something like this:
```
List<Request> requests =...;
Multi.createFrom().iterable(requests)
    .group().asList().of(100)
    .onItem().transformToMultiAndConcacenate(listOfOneHundred -> callTheServiceAndCreateAMultiWithTheResponses())
    . ....
```

Comment: Hi @Clement, I've updated my post with a new approach. I think I close to the solution, but the request are sent one by one, so I think I need the request to be sent in parallel in group of 100s. Thx

Comment: Instead of `transformToMultiAndConcatenate`, try with `transformToMulti(...).merge(100)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you create the multy wrong, it would be much easier to use this:

```
Multi<String> multiOfJokes = Multi.createFrom().emitter(multiEmitter -> {
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            multiEmitter.emit(i);
        }
        multiEmitter.complete();
    }).onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(index -> {
        return Uni.createFrom().item("String" + index);
    })
```

With this approach it should mace the call parallel.
Now is the question of how to make it to a list.

The grouping works fine
I run it with this code:

```
Random random = new Random();
    Multi<Integer> multiOfInteger = Multi.createFrom().emitter(multiEmitter -> {
        for (Integer i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            multiEmitter.emit(i);
        }
        multiEmitter.complete();
    });
    Multi<String> multiOfJokes = multiOfInteger.onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(index -> {
        if (index % 10 == 0 ) {
            Duration delay = Duration.ofMillis(random.nextInt(100) + 1);
            return Uni.createFrom().item("String " + index  + " delayed").onItem()
                    .delayIt().by(delay);
        }
        return Uni.createFrom().item("String" + index);
    }).onCompletion().invoke(() -> System.out.println("Completed"));
    Multi<List<String>> multiListJokes = multiOfJokes
            .group().intoLists().of(100)
            .onCompletion().invoke(() -> System.out.println("Completed"))
            .onItem().invoke(strings -> System.out.println(strings));
    multiListJokes.collect().asList().await().indefinitely();
```

You will get a list of your string.

I don't know, how you intend to send the list to backend.
But you can either to it with:

- call (executed asynchronously)
- write own subscriber (implements Subscriber) the methods are straight forward.
  As you need for your bulk request.

I hope you understand it better afterward.

PS: link to guide where I learned all of it:
https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides

Comment: Hi, thx for your response. I understand, the problem is to fit the Vert.x WebClient in that solution, because when I try to subscribe it, the calls are sent in paralell.

Comment: I thought you want to parallelize it. If not, you can replace transformToUniandMerge in a simple map. Then it should be serial again.
Or I don't understand what you mean with webclient.
If you generate a webclient with Quarkus, you don't need to think about it. The request gets always handled in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I want to parallel them but I want to use reactive approach too, because I can parallel the requests with Java ParallelStreams and it works! But I want to use mutiny and I need an async extension to make the calls. In this case, I'm using Vert.X WebClient that is an HTTP Async extension. I can use async-http extension too. When I launch the calls in parallel and async, everything seem works. However, the problem is the client launches thousand of requests, and the server raises a "Closed Connection" exception, so I want to launch them in blocks of 1000 (p.e). Thx

Comment: I am not sure, what my mistake is, but when you use the web client in the part of transform multi to Uni and merge, you will get parallel calls. It should be limited to 125 calls. As this function have a back pressure of 125. Therefore, at the start it asks for 125 entries and then, get a new one, when one thread is finished.
There shouldn't be thousands of parallel calls.

Comment: Do you have any link where I can read the limit should be 125? Becuause it's an interesting point. Thx

Comment: You can kinda read it from here:
https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-back-pressure/
For checking in code it looks like:
.onRequest().invoke(s -> System.out.println(s))
This prints the amount of requested items. In this case I was wrong, it is 256 on the first call. What you can see, when you plug this printer in. 
Unfortunately i don't know how to change this number.

Answer (score 0):

So in short you want to batch parallel calls to the server, without hitting it with everything at once.

Could this work for you? It uses `merge`. In my example, it has a parallelism of 2.

```
Multi.createFrom().range(1, 10)
            .onItem()
            .transformToUni(integer -> {
                return <<my long operation Uni>>
            })
            .merge(2) //this is the concurrency 
            .collect()
            .asList();
```

I'm not sure if `merge` was added later this year, but this seems to do what you want. In my example, the "long operation producing Uni" is actually a call to the Microprofile Rest Client which produces a Uni, and returns a string. After the `merge` you can put another `onItem` to perform something with the response (it's a plain `Multi` after the `merge`), instead of collecting everything as list.